# Could conversion to MP3 cause a the file to start earlier?

Tags: conversion, mp3, audacity, wav

I recorded a track(track1) in audacity on top of another track (track2)  and then exported only track1 as an mp3. it now seems that track1 kind of starts 1/2 a second early. Could this happened due to the conversion to mp3 ?

I know that is starts early, as the singing in the file starts a little earlier.

Comment: What's programming related about this?

Comment: You can hear a delay of a half second? Well, open up the track again in Audacity to check that.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no reason why conversion to MP3 would cause the file to start earlier (unless there's a bug in audacity).

The problem is probably somewhere else. Did you maybe accidentally shift the start of track1?

We will not be able to help you without more information.

Try to reproduce the problem in audacity, then post the exact steps you followed (and ideally the media file necessary to reproduce them, which you can put onto some webspace, as you cannot post it here), along with precise instructions to reproduce the problem. Then we'll see...